# How to get id value of li using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

Javascript:

```
let BLACKLIST_TOPICS = [];
if (getCookie('topics')) {
    BLACKLIST_TOPICS = (getCookie('topics')).split(',');
} 
const CONTENEUR_TOPICS = document.getElementsByClassName('topic-list topic-list-admin');
let TOPICS;
if (CONTENEUR_TOPICS.length > 0) {
    TOPICS = CONTENEUR_TOPICS[0].children;
}

function blacklistTopic() {
            for (let i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
                if (i != 13 && TOPICS) {
                    const result = /^(.+?)\n\t(.+)\t(.+)\t(.+)\t$/.exec(TOPICS[i].innerText);
                    for (let j = 0; j < BLACKLIST_TOPÏCS.length; j++){
                        if (result && result[2] == BLACKLIST_TOPICS[j]) {
                            topicBL.push(TOPICS[i]);
                            TOPICS[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Css:

```
 < ul class="topic-list topic-list-admin">
     < li class data-id="61825360"></li>
     < li class data-id="61824752"></li>
     < li class data-id="61826398"></li>
 < /ul>
```

I try to get a list of data-id value inside the array "result", using only javascript, no jquery

example:

```
result= [61825360, 61824752, 61826398]
```

Comment: `TOPICS[i]` doesn't have any `innerText`. I don't understand what you're trying to match with the regexp.

Comment: `data-id` values are in `TOPICS[i].dataset.id`.

Comment: Why are you looping `i` from 1 to 26 instead of `TOPICS.length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `dataset` property to get the value of a `data-XXX` attribute. You can loop over the topics, getting the `data-id` of each. use `.map()` to return them in an array.

```js
const CONTENEUR_TOPICS = document.getElementsByClassName('topic-list topic-list-admin');
let TOPICS;
if (CONTENEUR_TOPICS.length > 0) {
  TOPICS = CONTENEUR_TOPICS[0].children;
  let result = blacklistTopic(TOPICS);
  console.log(result);
}

function blacklistTopic(topics) {
  return Array.from(topics).map(el => el.dataset.id);
}
```

```html
<ul class="topic-list topic-list-admin">
  <li class data-id="61825360"></li>
  <li class data-id="61824752"></li>
  <li class data-id="61826398"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.topic-list li')

var result = []
for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
   result.push(result[i].getAttribute('data-id'))
}

console.log(result)
```